# How to show all div's inside images titles onmouseover?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewcontroller

I have a div containing images and I want to show all of the inside image's titles onmouseover.

So, I have something like this :

```
<div id=MyDiv onmouseover="highlight(this);">
```

And my javascript :

```
function highlight(element) {     

        for (var i = 0; i < element.children.length; i++) {
            if (element.children[i].tagName == "IMG")
                element.children[i].title.show();
        }
    }
```

But all i get is a message - Object "X" has no method show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using jQuery:

HTML:

```
<div id="MyDiv">
    <img src="http://chandra.harvard.edu/photo/2012/m101/m101_xray_thm100.jpg" title="img1" />
    <img src="http://passport-cdn.mobilenations.com/avatars/000/004/072/100x100_4072871.jpg?r=1" title="img2" />
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#MyDiv").mouseenter(function () {
    $mydiv = $(this);
    $.each($('img', $mydiv), function () {
        var pos = $(this).position();
        $('<div>', {
            class: 'imgtitle'
        }).css({
            position: 'absolute',
            color: 'red',
            top: pos.top + 5,
            left: pos.left + 5
        })
        .html($(this).attr('title'))
        .insertAfter($(this));
    });
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $('.imgtitle').remove();
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle showing it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/obryckim/k5hcJ/

Answer (score 2):

You are using plain JavaScript. `title` is a string, and as the message says, it has no method `show`.

If what you want to do is alert all the titles in a pop-up, you can do this:

```
function highlight(element) {     

        for (var i = 0; i < element.children.length; i++) {
            if (element.children[i].tagName == "IMG")
                alert(element.children[i].title);
        }
    }
```

If, on the other hand you want to show them on your page you need something like this:

```
function highlight(element) {     
        var outputelement = document.getElementById("idofsomeelementyouhaveonyourpage");
        for (var i = 0; i < element.children.length; i++) {
            if (element.children[i].tagName == "IMG")
                outputelement.innerHTML += element.children[i].title;
        }
    }
```

Of course, with the second method, you'd need an `onmouseout` handler that hides the titles as well.